# Nodejs networking - realtime communication

Tags: real-time, node.js

I'm new to node.js and I want to ask a simple question about how it works.

I have used FMs in the past for client to client communication and real time applications. For example, for creating a collaborative application where you need to see what other users are doing. I want to explore that using NodeJS.

I have couple of questions:

1) How does NodeJs handle server-to-client communication? Is thee any way to push information to the client? or the client needs to be making requests constantly to the server to see if anything has changed?

2) Is there such thing like permanent connections between the server and the clients?

3) How Can be handle client-to-client communication (of course thru the server)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Node itself can talk HTTP as well as lower-level TCP & Unix sockets. The client that connects therefore determines some of the capabilities. Are you talking here about a browser client or some other type of client?

Comment: Socket.IO is the way to go with browser clients as noted below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 3) How Can be handle client-to-client
>   communication (of course thru the
>   server)?

A simple solution is to open a websocket between the server and each client :

[Client A] <==websocket==> [Server] <==websocket==> [Client B]

If you go with Socket.IO for example, it is very easy to do client-to-client communication this way.

When the server receives a message from one client, you just broadcast it to all clients or send it to one specific client depending on your use case.

Some example code using Socket.IO :

```
var socket = io.listen(server);
socket.on('connection', function(client) {
  client.on('message', function(msg) {
    broadcast(msg); // broadcast message to all clients
    // OR
    socket.clients[session_id].send(msg); // send message to one client
  });

  client.on('disconnect', function( ) {
    console.log('Client Disconnected.');
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by cross-platform ? My sample code is for Socket.IO-node, the server-side component of Socket.IO. As for client-side, yes it should work with all browsers thanks to many fallbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a lot of Node.js questions from you recently ;)

1. As Toby already said, Node can do HTTP, TCP/UDP and Unix Sockets. When you establish a permanent connection, you can of course push data to the clients.
2. Since you are talking about Browser based clients, there a numerous ways to achieve this. You could for example use WebSockets with a Flash fallback. In case you are not interested in the low level details and  want a complete package, take a look at [Socket.IO](http://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO).
3. WebSockets can't do this, Flash can't do it either as far as I know. So unless you want to enter Java/Silverlight land, you'll need to route the requests through your server.

Comment: thank!. These questions are based on my experience with Flash Platform and Flash Media Server. With FMS, once the clients are connected you can to route messages from from client to another. This is the kind of functionality I want to test using Node.JS.. I need to find out how reliable it is and if it will work on all browsers.

Comment: It should work without problems in browser which support WebSockets natively(Chrome 5+, Safari 5, Firefox 4 Beta), flash fallbacks will always be laggy. Socket.IO has even more fall backs. And even though these are made to behave like real sockets, they're in fact not and may be laggy or erroneous at times.